# Viewing Power BI Report from Web Pages

Tags: powerbi

We have developed the Power BI reports and published the Power BI report to the Power BI Workspace which I have created in Power BI Service.

Also, I have a Power BI Pro License.

Now I need to call the Power BI report (which is available in the Power BI Workspace) from the web application through button click event.

The end users will be accessing the web application and access the Power BI report from the Web application (on button click) to view the reports/dashboards.

Now I want to know, Viewing the Power BI report from web application the end users will need Power BI license? If yes, please provide the necessary details.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because licensing questions are off-topic

Comment: Are your users with the same organisation as you or outside external users?